# York affinity 8t outside fan won't start. Replaced the capacitor

Tags: air-conditioning, fans, capacitor

I have a York Affinity 8T AC unit. On June 20, it stopped cooling the house.  I saw that the outside fan was not running.

After a bit of Googling, I decided to try replacing the capacitor, 30+5.0 +- 6% 440 V.  Ordered the same one online for $20.  It arrived on the 23rd.

I installed it, and the fan came on.  The house got down to the set temp.  When the thermostat called for cool air again, the fan didn't come on.

I ordered a multimeter with MFD to test the capacitor.  It arrived on the 28th.  I pulled the capacitor and it tested fine.  I reinstalled it, and just for the heck of it, I tried the AC.  The fan came on, and the house cooled down to the set temp again.

But just like the last time, when the thermostat called for more cool air, the fan didn't come on.  Spinning the fan by hand doesn't help to get it started.

Comment: At least you did not need to spend a lot of money so far.  The problem is somewhere else.  Will need to do more tests, or get someone in to do the testing to find the problem,  might just be a loose connection or something else.  Replacing parts to find a problem tends to get expensive.

Comment: Could be an issue with the thermostat, not the AC unit.

Comment: @crip659 - The capacitor was cheap, and the multimeter, well I consider tools an investment.  So yes, not much in it so far.  I will be checking all the connections and wires.

Comment: @FreeMan - I have an identical setup in another house.  I'm going to try switching the thermostats to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Make sure you take pics of the wiring of both 'stats in both houses before you remove them. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for the heads up.  The bases are wired and stay on the wall.  The stats pop off the bases.